# Syntax error with simple mysql transaction

Tags: mysql, pdo, transactions

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I am fairly new to transactions, it seems I need one for inserting the next auto incremented ID.

Here's the query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO posts (title, text, user, club, time) 
VALUES ('$title', '$text', '$name', '$club', '$time');
INSERT INTO post_likes (user, post) 
VALUES ('$name', LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT;
```

The syntax error cuts me off right before INSERT INTO posts.

Comment: PDO only supports issuing one query statement at a time. The `START/END TRANSACTION` events count each as a statement themselves, and it will report a syntax error. Use `$pdo->beginTransaction()` and `$pdo->commit()`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php, then issue each `INSERT` statement as a separate query.

Comment: This should have been the answer! +1 @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @TimeBigot Can you please post the contextual PHP/PDO code in which you are executing this? That will help us to craft an appropriate correction without making assumptions on how you are trying to use this.

Comment: That did it! THANKS! if i post any other questions in the future, ill remember that michael. im a little new here.

Comment: Hey @MichaelBerkowski , do you mind posting your comment as an answer please?

Comment: @Barett Sure, I expanded it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO's `query()` and `prepare()` methods only support single SQL statements per execution, but by calling `START TRANSACTION/COMMIT`, together with the error message pointing to incorrect syntax near `INSERT`, we must assume you are attempting to execute all of those statements at once. That won't work, as PDO won't separate them on the `;` delimiter before execution.

PDO supplies API methods to handle the transaction in code, rather than needing to execute SQL statements, via [`PDO::beginTransaction()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) and [`PDO::commit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php). So you must separate the two `INSERT` statements, and wrap them in the transaction methods, calling `query()` or `prepare()/execute()` twice.

```
// Assuming your PDO connection is $pdo...
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO posts (title, text, user, club, time)  VALUES ('$title', '$text', '$name', '$club', '$time')");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO post_likes (user, post)  VALUES ('$name', LAST_INSERT_ID())");
$pdo->commit();
```

Now, not seeing your original PDO code, I am making an assumption about how you're currently executing it using variables directly. **We can make a major improvement**.

PDO has excellent support for prepared statements, which offer strong protection against SQL injection. Let's switch out the two `query()` calls for [`prepare()/execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) using named parameters.  Additionally, if you wish, you may substitute [`$pdo->lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) for MySQL's native `LAST_INSERT_ID()` if you wish.

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

// Prepare the first statement
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (title, text, user, club, time) VALUES (:title, :text, :user, :club, :time)');
// Execute the statement with an array of bound values
$stmt->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':text' => $text, ':user' => $user, ':club' => $club, ':time' => $time));

// Prepare & execute the second one
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO post_likes (user, post)  VALUES (:name, :post)');
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':post' => $pdo->lastInsertId()));

// Commit it
$pdo->commit();
```

Answer (score -2):

Quote time and user with backticks, it is a reserved word:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO posts (title, text, `user`, club, `time`) VALUES ('$title', '$text', '$name', '$club', '$time');
INSERT INTO post_likes (user, post) VALUES ('$name', LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT;
```

If ANSI SQL mode is on you can use " (double quotes) as well.

[See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Nope. TIME is not reserved (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) - this is a matter of PDO not supporting multiple statements.

Comment: The page says _Reserved keywords are marked with (R)_.  TIME is a keyword as a function name, but not a reserved one requiring quoting.

Comment: `USER` is also not a reserved word.

Comment: And the question says that the error happens at `INSERT INTO`, not at `user` or `time`.

Comment: didnt know what the big deal was with reserved words til today. ill make sure to change them out. thanks.